# Level shifting a 0-5V signal to 0-16V

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, analog, dac

I have a Atmel microcontroller with 0-5V DAC output and I want to shift it to 0-16V (16V max. normal between 11-16V).

It need an output signal with max. ~1mA, short protection and reverse polarity protection.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Use an amplifier.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do what you ask. The op-amp has internal short-circuit protection but it is not effective for supply voltages higher than 15V, so we add R3 and a bypass cap. Shorting or applying a negative voltage to the output will not damage the chip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJsd5f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! 
V1 =24V is that necessary? Or can also 11-16V for V1? 
I need form 0-5V input to ~ 0 - V1(11-16V) output.
With reverse protection i mean if somebody connect V1 to the OP output
Can I also put a diode in series after R3 for protection?

Comment: Depending on your op-amp you may need as much as 18V to get 16V out. The higher voltage (24V) allows a higher resistance of R3 which provides more protection. With an LM358 and 11V you might only get 8-9.5V out maximum. You don't need a diode with the circuit I suggest.

Comment: Hm, what if when i only had V1 with 11-16V and need output of max. nearly V1 ~ -0.5V ?

Comment: Better to use  a somewhat better op-amp (rail-to-rail output only or RRIO).

Comment: Do you have a schematic for that and an op-amp recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

A simple operational amplifier summer with a constant 11 DC volt signal would do the job.

Most probably you'll need a 18V or so power supply to do it. Reverse polarity protection *on an output* doesn't make much sense, you should clarify what you mean.

Given that you only need 1mA if the input driven is high impedance you could simply use a resistor to limit the current (or use a protected amplifier, many have some kind of protection).